# how do I use __str__ method python

Tags: string, python-3.x, methods

How do I use the str method to display list with comma-separated and square brackets
for example :

test:

> my_list = UnorderedList()
>
> for i in range(5):
>
> ```
>   my_list.add(i)
> ```
>
> print(my_list)

result:

> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print a string `"[1, 2, 3]"`? Or you want `['1', '2', '3']`?

Comment: @Dannnno i want to print a string [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Can you rephrase your question with input and output ?

Comment: Your header and content doesn't looks to be matching.

Answer (score 1):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function (or statement, in Python 2.x) already calls `str` on its arguments, so you don't have to do *anything*:

```
>>> print([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print([])
[]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

As the documentation says:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream…

---

If you want to get the string for some other purpose besides printing (e.g., to write to a file), you can always call [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on it. It's just a function like any other (well, a type constructor, but don't worry about that):

```
>>> s = str(a)
>>> s
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

As the docs explain:

> `str(object)` returns [`object.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method, then `str()` falls back to returning [`repr(object)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Comment: @12345678: OK, good; I wrote the answer for Python 3 (with just one little parenthetical for Python 2), and all the links go to Python 3 docs. (But you should edit the `python-3.x` tag into your question, because a lot of people still assume Python 2.7 if you don't say otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `str()` function and pass the list as argument you want to display. for example,

```
tmp_list = [1,2,3,4]

print str(tmp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are used for providing string representation and used repr used to provide object representation specially when object represented in console or print

````
class StringRepresentation:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "String Representation of Object used when object used as string represenation"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Object Representation"


obj = StringRepresentation()
print(str(obj))```

UnorderedList is printing because this is the way how it __str__ or __repr__ is implemented
````